# Functional any difference between using Object.create and simply reassigning to prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype

I was wondering if there is any difference between using Object.create() and simply reassigning?

Using Object.create()

```
function Rectangle(length, width) {
  this.length = length;
  this.width = width;
}

function Square(size) {
  this.length = size;
  this.width = size;
}

Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    value: square,
    writable: true
  }
});
```

Reassigning

```
function Rectangle(length, width) {
  this.length = length;
  this.width = width;
}

function Square(size) {
  this.length = size;
  this.width = size;
}

Square.prototype = Rectangle.prototype;
Square.prototype.constructor = Square;
```